# How to load external configuration files in NodeJS dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching

In a NodeJS application I would like to load configuration data (reports to be generated) from external files dynamically. I can load them statically by using require('path/config');

But I do have parts of the configuration that need to be refreshed on a regular schedule and, to make it all more complicated, these configuration files contain a function that must be executable.

One such report looks as follows:

```
const report = {
  name : 'Report 3',
  description : 'Very simple report.',
  // Some properties
  preprocessor : function() {
  },
  // Some more properties
};

module.exports = report;
```

When using require to re-load the report it is basically not reloaded. Even if I change something, it stays the same. (Reason: require() uses caching and rightfully it does.)

What is a good way (maybe an external library) to re-load external configuration files that contain executable functions?

Comment: why not use an additional function in report.js that 'runs' everything else? then require report.js and set a timeout that calls that new function on whatever schedule you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). If you have complete control over the configuration files (otherwise it's dangerous) you can use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

```
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.readFileSync(filename);
var module = {}
eval(file);

// You can access report in module.exports
```

If you don't want to block your application (usually recommended) you should use [the async version](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) and provide callbacks.

Comment: JSON.parse unfortunately cannot handle executable JavaScript, only JSON as it seems.

Comment: Sorry for the assumption. I updated the reply to use eval.

Comment: Problem with eval: It doesn't return an object to use.

Comment: I realized that and did another edit (I'm sorry I didn't warn you). In a local nodejs test I was able to `eval` a piece of code that had the typical `module.exports` and was able to retrieve the `const` by reading `module.exports` after the `eval`. On the other hand that's ugly and your solution is way nicer.

Answer (score 0):

To circument caching problems, I now use the library [require-without-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-without-cache). Seems to do the job.